# Get all 1-k tuples in a n-tuple

Tags: java, tuples, powerset

With n=5 and k=3 the following loop will do it

```
List<String> l=new ArrayList<String>();
l.add("A");l.add("B");l.add("C");l.add("D");l.add("E");
int broadcastSize = (int) Math.pow(2, l.size());
for (int i = 1; i < broadcastSize; i++) {
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(50);
    int mask = i;
    int j = 0;   
    int size=0;
    System.out.println();
    while (mask > 0) {
        if ((mask & 1) == 1) {
            System.out.println(".. "+mask);
            buffer.append(l.get(j));
            if (++size>3){
                buffer = new StringBuffer(50);
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(" "+mask);
        mask >>= 1;
        j++;
    }
    if (buffer.length()>0)
        System.out.println(buffer.toString());

}
```

but it's not efficient I would like to do it with [Banker's sequence](http://applied-math.org/subset.pdf) and thus explore first singletons, then pairs, then 3-tuple and stop.

I did not find a way do that, but at least this loop should be more efficient:

```
List<String> l=new ArrayList<String>();
l.add("A");l.add("B");l.add("C");l.add("D");l.add("E");
int broadcastSize = (int) Math.pow(2, l.size());
for (int i = 1; i < broadcastSize; i++) {
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(50);
    int mask = i;
    int j = 0;   

    if (StringUtils.countMatches(Integer.toBinaryString(i), "1") < 4){
        while (mask > 0) {
            if ((mask & 1) == 1) {
                buffer.append(l.get(j));

            }
            mask >>= 1;
            j++;
        }
        if (buffer.length()>0)
            System.out.println(buffer.toString());
    }


}
```

there is also: but k embedded loops looks ugly

```
//singleton
for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(l.get(i));
}

//pairs
for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < l.size(); j++) {
        System.out.println(l.get(i)+l.get(j));
    }
}

//3-tuple
for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < l.size(); j++) {
        for (int k = j+1; k < l.size(); k++) {
            System.out.println(l.get(i)+l.get(j)+l.get(k));
        }
    }
}
//...
// k-tuple
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should be the most efficient way, even if k embedded loops looks ugly

```
//singleton
for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(l.get(i));
}

//pairs
for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < l.size(); j++) {
        System.out.println(l.get(i)+l.get(j));
    }
}

//3-tuple
for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < l.size(); j++) {
        for (int k = j+1; k < l.size(); k++) {
            System.out.println(l.get(i)+l.get(j)+l.get(k));
        }
    }
}
// ...
//k-tuple
```

Answer (score 4):

This technique is called [Gosper's hack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system#Applications).  It only works for `n <= 32` because it uses the bits of an `int`, but you can increase it to 64 if you use a `long`.

```
int nextCombo(int x) {
  // moves to the next combination with the same number of 1 bits
  int u = x & (-x);
  int v = u + x;
  return v + (((v ^ x) / u) >> 2);
}

...
for (int x = (1 << k) - 1; (x >>> n) == 0; x = nextCombo(x)) {
  System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(x));
}
```

For `n = 5` and `k = 3`, this prints

```
111
1011
1101
1110
10011
10101
10110
11001
11010
11100
```

exactly as you'd expect.

Comment: x is undefined in the first method, is it n?

Comment: Thx , I would need it for k in {1,2,3} then

Comment: Well...then just add a `for` loop that iterates `k` from `1` to `3`.

Comment: I'm deceived by performances: http://pastebin.com/K11EpjV5 my solution looks faster

Comment: k=4 http://pastebin.com/qa42Tnb2 p1: 213052 duration:124 ms
p2: 213052 duration:109 ms (p2 yours)

Comment: Of course your solution is faster, but it only works for fixed `k`.  This works generally for any `k`.

Answer (score 0):

Apache commons has iterators for [subsets](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/math3/util/Combinations.html) of size k, and for [permutations](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/iterators/PermutationIterator.html).
Here is an iterator that iterates through 1-k tuples of an n-tuple, that combines the two:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.collections4.iterators.PermutationIterator;
import org.apache.commons.math3.util.Combinations;

public class AllTuplesUpToKIterator implements Iterator<List<Integer>> {
    private Iterator<int[]> combinationIterator;
    private PermutationIterator<Integer> permutationIterator;
    int i;
    int k;
    int n;

    public AllTuplesUpToKIterator(int n, int k) {
        this.i = 1;
        this.k = k;
        this.n = n;
        combinationIterator = new Combinations(n, 1).iterator();
        permutationIterator = new PermutationIterator<Integer>(intArrayToIntegerList(combinationIterator.next()));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (permutationIterator.hasNext()) {
            return true;
        } else if (combinationIterator.hasNext()) {
            return true;
        } else if (i<k) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<Integer> next() {
        if (!permutationIterator.hasNext()) {
            if (!combinationIterator.hasNext()) {
                i++;
                combinationIterator = new Combinations(n, i).iterator();
            }
            permutationIterator = new PermutationIterator<Integer>(intArrayToIntegerList(combinationIterator.next()));          
        }
        return permutationIterator.next();
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public static List<Integer> intArrayToIntegerList(int[] arr) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i=0; i< arr.length; i++) {
            result.add(arr[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 4;
        int k = 2;
        for (AllTuplesUpToKIterator iter= new AllTuplesUpToKIterator(n, k); iter.hasNext();) {
            System.out.println(iter.next());
        }

    }
}
```